# MySQL Query missing from the slow query log

Tags: mysql

I've been looking at queries creating many temporary tables in the performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest.

```
FROM performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest 
where SUM_CREATED_TMP_TABLES > 0 and digest is not NULL 
order by SUM_CREATED_TMP_TABLES desc limit 1\G
```

I have a clear worst offender:

```
                 COUNT_STAR: 76703
             SUM_TIMER_WAIT: 96029343223000
             MIN_TIMER_WAIT: 631886000
             AVG_TIMER_WAIT: 1251963000
             MAX_TIMER_WAIT: 19597013000
              SUM_LOCK_TIME: 14475751000000
                 SUM_ERRORS: 0
               SUM_WARNINGS: 0
          SUM_ROWS_AFFECTED: 0
              SUM_ROWS_SENT: 1125890
          SUM_ROWS_EXAMINED: 29941322
SUM_CREATED_TMP_DISK_TABLES: 0
     SUM_CREATED_TMP_TABLES: 76742
       SUM_SELECT_FULL_JOIN: 0
 SUM_SELECT_FULL_RANGE_JOIN: 0
           SUM_SELECT_RANGE: 76754
     SUM_SELECT_RANGE_CHECK: 0
            SUM_SELECT_SCAN: 0
      SUM_SORT_MERGE_PASSES: 0
             SUM_SORT_RANGE: 0
              SUM_SORT_ROWS: 0
              SUM_SORT_SCAN: 0
          SUM_NO_INDEX_USED: 0
     SUM_NO_GOOD_INDEX_USED: 0
                 FIRST_SEEN: 2019-09-25 00:08:30
                  LAST_SEEN: 2019-09-25 11:22:49
```

If my understanding is correct.  The above suggests the query has been executed 76,703 times since 2019-09-25 00:08:30 and created 76,754 temporary tables.  Implicitly.

What I don't understand is that if I set the long_query_time to 0 the query does not show up in the slow query log.
I thought if the long_query_time was set to 0 all queries are written to the log.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *if I set the long_query_time to 0 the query does not show up in the slow query log* Check global `slow_query_log` and `slow_query_log_file` system variables. Maybe this logging is disabled?

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Both are switched on.  I am getting some queries.  But not the one referenced above.

Comment: SET GLOBAL min_examined_row_limit=1; and SET GLOBAL long_query_time=.001; for 5 minutes and you will see it in the SQLog. When you get to digging, you will find the query needs indexes to avoid creating temp tables.  EXPLAIN SELECT ....... will make the missing index obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Vinicius@Percona.  He explained the reason the query does not appear in the slow query log is due to the fact that existing connections are not impacted by the long_query_time being changed.  Only new connections.

Answer (score -2):

by 8adger on Sep 25, 2019  "I thought if the long_query_time was set to 0 all queries are written to the log."

Wrong thought.  When long_query_time = 0, NO queries are logged to the Slow Query Log.

Comment: WFM.  I don't think that is the case.  Can you point to documentation on it?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: Hmmm; I am still blind to it.  There are 3 mentions of `long_query_time` on that page, none indicating that `=0` disables logging.

Comment: The slow query log consists of SQL statements that take more than long_query_time seconds to execute and require at least min_examined_row_limit rows to be examined.

Comment: So, the "wrong thought" needs a qualification about `min_examined_row_limit`??

Comment: Reading the whole refman article has more than 20 underlined considerations.  These two are primary qualifiers.